# How do we find the current in this circuit?

Tags: current, kirchhoffs-laws

How do I find the current drawn by the 11V in this circuit? I understand that the circuit can be redrawn but I do not understand the simplifying procedures to do so.

[image: circuit]

Comment: You have a resistor tetrahedron where all vertices are connected to edges composed of one each from R1, R2, and R3 and where all faces are bounded also by one each from R1, R2, and R3. Finally, both vertices connected by one of the R2 edges go to ground (-) via R1 and both vertices connected by the other R2 edge goes to the supply rail (+), also via R1. What tools are you allowed to apply?

Comment: @jonk: Thanks, no restrictions on the tools, but since this is a time-bound test, they are looking for the fastest way to solve.

Comment: There's a nice symmetry to apply. It really helps a lot to simplify the problem.

Comment: Who is the "they" who are giving this "time-bound test"? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It is really simpler. Symmetry -> R2 : no current -> short it. Then resistors in parallel is obvious ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no general rules for simplifying circuitry like this.

Look for places where there are components in series or in parallel. Simplify them to a single component.

Look for components directly in parallel with voltage sources - that component can only affect the current in the voltage source but not affect any other part of the circuit, in many cases it can be removed as it won't affect the goal of the analysis.

In circuits for simulation look for ideal current sources in series with any other component - that component will not affect the current and can removed and shorted out.

For this particular one we can use symmetry to determine nodes of the same potential. Any resistors across those nodes can be replaced by a short-circuit (or an open circuit if appropriate) as that won't affect the overall result.

By observation the voltage at each end of the resistors marked R2 are the same. If we replace each of them by a short circuit it can be seen that the top two R1's are in parallel and so are the bottom two R1's so can each be replaced by a resistor of R1/2.

The middle section consists of two R1's and two R3's all in parallel. The can be replaced by a single resistor of equivalent value equal to R1//R1//R3//R3. (// meaning in parallel with).

The two R1's at the bottom can be replaced with a resistor of value R1/2.

The circuit has been reduced to three resistors in series R1/2 + R1/2  + (R1//R1//R3//R3).

The current can then be easily calculated.

It would be easier to describe if every element had a unique reference.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways of looking at it, so I'll give you one that works for me. We'll exploit symmetry.

First, observe that due to symmetry, the potentials at the ends of R2 are the same, so it doesn't matter which end of R2 are R3's connected to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjUxoB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, the symmetry is even more obvious, and we note that R2 definitely have no potential across them, since both branches of the circuit are identical. So we can remove R2's.

Then we can merge the two branches of the circuit, by doubling the conductances of all elements (or halving their resistances).

Finally, we merge the two series-connected R1/2 elements into a single R1 element.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv5oPj.png)</sup>

The equivalent load resistance connected to the voltage source is, thus:

$$R_L = R_1 + {1 \over {2 \over R_1} + {2 \over R_3} }.$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwblFO.png)</sup>

All of the above circuits simulate "live" as soon as you open them. Note how we use the variables called R1, R2, and R3 to set all the resistances. We can then easily write expressions that use them, up to and including setting the expression for RL. Note how the load current is equal in the original and final reduction of the circuit.